OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError when trying to set discriminator.trainable property
I'm training a GAN based on the pix2pix architecture, and my training code works in Eager mode. Putting it in graph mode returns the following error:
    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. You can attempt the following resolutions to the problem: If you are running in Graph mode, use Eager execution mode or decorate this function with @tf.function. If you are using AutoGraph, you can try decorating this function with @tf.function. If that does not work, then you may be using an unsupported feature or your source code may not be visible to AutoGraph. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.

I have created the following minimal reproducible example, assuming a discriminator (simply a CNN with one Dense, sigmoid-activated output layer) has been defined:
@tf.function
def f():
    for epoch in tf.range(1):
        discriminator.trainable = True

f()

Putting the program in Eager mode fixes the issue. I'm not sure why the program thinks I'm trying to assign a bool to a Tensor, since I'm just setting a boolean property trainable to True.

Rule of thumb: You cannot do "Python stuff" in graph mode, only "Tensorflow stuff" (computations on tensors). Changing an attribute of a Python object falls under "Python stuff", so this line should not be in a tf.function context.
